# Best way to check if list contains at least one of an enum

Tags: java, collections, enums

I have an enum :

```
public enum PermissionsEnum {
    ABC("Abc"),        
    XYZ("Xyz"),
    ....
}
```

And then I have a list of Strings. I want to check if my list has at least one of the enums. I currently check it by an iterative approach. I also know there is a way to do it by using `||` checking `list.contains(enum.ABC..) || list.contains(enum.XYZ) || ...`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Instead of dealing with a `List<String>` you should consider going with an `EnumSet<PermissionsEnum>` right from the start. If its empty there are no permissions, no need to do any clumsy checks.

Comment: Not quite certain what you are asking. You will always have to iterate the list but are you also iterating the `enum`? If so that can be improved with a `HashSet` or `EnumSet`.

Comment: you could use streams and find the first element that is returned when the condition is: element instanceof enumClass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `List<String>` never contains a `PermissionsEnum` value.

The condition `list.contains(enum.ABC) || list.contains(enum.XYZ)` is not going to be working.

Instead, you could map `PermissionsEnum.values()` to a `Stream<String>` and call `Stream#anyMatch` on it:

```
boolean result = Arrays.stream(PermissionsEnum.values())
                       .map(PermissionsEnum::getValue)
                       .anyMatch(list::contains);
```

*I assumed that constructor parameter is accessible by the `getValue` method.

---

In case the list is large (a few iterations over it might take a lot of time) we could optimise the previous snippet a bit and iterate over the list once:

```
Set<String> values = Arrays.stream(PermissionsEnum.values())
                           .map(PermissionsEnum::getValue)
                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());

boolean result = list.stream().anyMatch(values::contains);
```

Comment: Are you sure `values::contains` is correct here? Because I get the enums as an array in the first step, but 'm not getting the correct result from step 2.

Comment: for the list `Arrays.asList("Xyz")`, both snippets return `true`

Comment: Oh yes. I should update my question then, what if I have a list of `PermissionEnums` instead of `String` list?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily in an iterative way with a for loop.

```
boolean contains = false;
for (PermissionsEnum permission : PermissionsEnum.values()) {
    if (list.contains(permission.getName())) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can use `Collections.disjoint()` like this:

```
Set<String> permissionsNames = Stream.of(PermissionsEnum.values())
                                     .map(PermissionsEnum::getName())
                                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());

boolean contains = !Collections.disjoint(list, permissionsNames);
```

PS: `getName()` must retrieve the constructor value.

Comment: Upvoted for using `Collections.disjoint`. However, `Collections.disjoint` is optimized in case one of the collections it receives is a `Set`. So I'd only change `Collectors.toList()` to `Collectors.toSet()` and you'd get some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `java.util.List.containsAll(Collection<?> c)` which returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the specified collection.

```
List permissionEnumList = Arrays.asList(PermissionsEnum.values());
List tobeCheckedEnumList= Arrays.asList(PermissionsEnum.ABC);
boolean result= permissionEnumList.containsAll(tobeCheckedEnumList);
```