# Check if list contains at least one of another - enums

Tags: java, enums, java-8

I have an enum :

```
public enum PermissionsEnum {
    ABC("Abc"),        
    XYZ("Xyz"),
    ....
}
```

And then I have a list of **Enums**. I want to check if my list has at least one of the enums. I currently check it by an iterative approach. I also know there is a way to do it by using `||` checking `list.contains(enum.ABC..) || list.contains(enum.XYZ) || ...`.

Is there a better way to do it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747276/best-way-to-check-if-list-contains-at-least-one-of-an-enum) shows how to do it if the objective list is a list of Strings, I want to get the matching status if the list is another list of enums.

Comment: try `!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);` to check if list2 contains elements form list2

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I want to check if my list (of enums) has at least one of the enums". Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if you have a `List<PermissionEnum>`, aren't all elements one of those enums? Aside from that, the best way to store a collection of enums is in an `EnumSet`, because it doesn't make sense to have the same permission twice or more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Collections.disjoint` returns `true` if the two specified collections have no elements in common. If it returns `false`, then your list has at least one of the enums.

```
boolean contains = !Collections.disjoint(list, EnumSet.allOf(PermissionsEnum.class)));
```

A Stream API approach could be:

```
EnumSet<PermissionsEnum> set = EnumSet.allOf(PermissionsEnum.class);
boolean contains = list.stream().anyMatch(set::contains);
```

(similar to an iterative approach but with parallelisation included)

Comment: Instead of `asList(PermissionsEnum.values())`, I’d use `EnumSet.allOf(PermissionsEnum.class)` which returns a `Set` having O(1) lookup and further doesn’t need an array copy of all values. Further, I’d not be so quick in inserting `parallelStream()`, as it’s rather unlikely that the list is so humongous that performing such a trivial operation in parallel has a benefit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Collections.disjoint()`.

Create another List with the enums you want to check and then do
`Collections.disjoint(list, listOfEnumsToCheck)`. It returns true if no elements are found. If it is false at least one element is present.

I guess you can even use Enum.values() so it will become:

```
// Using ! to show there is at least one value
if (!Collections.disjoint(list, PermissionsEnum.values()) { 
     doStuff 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `java-8`.

```
Arrays.stream(PermissionsEnum.values()).anyMatch(list::contains);
```

`Enum#values()`

> Returns an array containing the constants of this enum  type.

So we just need to wrap it into a stream and check if list contains any values. Important thing to remember is that

> anyMatch not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary
>   for determining the result.

In other words it may return true as soon as element which satisfies predicate is found.

Apparently, more efficient way is to use `EnumSet.allOf(PermissionsEnum.class)::contains` because `EnumSet.contains` is much more efficient than `List.contains`:

```
list.stream().anyMatch(EnumSet.allOf(PermissionsEnum.class)::contains)
```

Comment: `list.stream().anyMatch(EnumSet.allOf(PermissionsEnum.class)::contains)` is preferable as `EnumSet.contains` is much more efficient than `List.contains` for all common `List` implementations…

Comment: @Holger, thanks a lot for your comment, I didn't know that, will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a static list in a Type Safe Enum Pattern enum to act as the master list, which is added to in the enum constructor. That way your master list always contains exactly one of each enum, and you can compare to that.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EnumeratedEnum {
    public static final ArrayList<EnumeratedEnum> Members=new ArrayList<>();
    private final String value;
    public String getValue() {return value;}
    private EnumeratedEnum(String value) {
        this.value=value;
        Members.add(this);
    }
    public static final EnumeratedEnum EnumOne=new EnumeratedEnum("someValue");
    public static final EnumeratedEnum EnumTwo=new EnumeratedEnum("someValue2");
    public static final EnumeratedEnum EnumThree=new EnumeratedEnum("someValue3");
    public static final EnumeratedEnum EnumFour=new EnumeratedEnum("someValue4");
    public static final EnumeratedEnum EnumFive=new EnumeratedEnum("someValue5");
}
```